# Is there a configuration setting for JBoss 5.0 to control the order in which ear files are deployed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss

Is there a mechanism either within the ear file itself (jboss-app.xml) or a configuration on the server to ensure that an EAR is loaded last and/or after another ear?  For example

1. /deploy/web-services.ear  (owned by
   another vendor/project)
2. /deploy/enterprise-app.ear (war,
   ejbs web services)

something like:

```
<load-precedence>
web-services.ear
enterprise-app.ear
</load-precedence>
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be handy if there was; I don't know of one.  We have EAR's that depend on other EARs.  Our startup code runs in a thread and re-tries on an interval until the EJB's in the other EAR are available.

Comment: Vote it up - maybe we will get an answer :-).

Answer (score 2):

I've never used JBoss as an app server but looking at this documentation:

[JBOSS DeploymentScanner](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringTheDeploymentScannerInConfjbossSystemxml)

There is a Deployment Sorter that seems like it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The article appears to be for JBOSS 4 or earlier.  I can't find any of these entries in jboss-service.xml on JBOSS 5.0 or JBOSS 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using EAR suffix configuration order in `conf/bootstrap/deployers.xml`. The value is ranged from 50 (started first) and 950 (started last), see [LegacyDeploymentContextComparator class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-system/5.1.0.Beta1/org/jboss/system/deployers/LegacyDeploymentContextComparator.java#LegacyDeploymentContextComparator.0suffixOrder). In your case you would get:

```
<bean name="topContextComparator">
    <constructor factoryClass="org.jboss.system.deployers.LegacyDeploymentContextComparator" factoryMethod="getInstance"/>
     <property name="suffixOrder" class="java.util.Map">
        <map keyClass="java.lang.String" valueClass="java.lang.Integer">
            <entry>
                <key>web-services.ear</key>
                <value>500</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>enterprise-app.ear</key>
                <value>600</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I also use generic suffix configuration such as `_<N>.ear` where `<N>` is the starting order. This avoids changing the `deployers.xml` file each time I deploy a new EAR. This is useful when deploying versioned EARs such as `MyEar_v20130611_3.ear` (in that case N=3):

```
            <entry>
                <key>_1.ear</key>
                <value>500</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>_2.ear</key>
                <value>600</value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>_3.ear</key>
                <value>700</value>
            </entry>
```